# Thesis: How to mark variables from software in text?

Tags: thesis, computer-science

I am writing a thesis about a web application that I developed. I sometimes need to reference a variable or type from the code. This happens quite a lot in the maintenance guide that I am also writing. They appear in the middle of the text so creating a code block for them is no option.

Does anyone know the proper way to mark them?
I came up with these ideas:

1. The "greenhouseData" needs to....
2. The greenhouseData needs to....
3. The <greenhouseData> needs to....

Comment: Every editor/school/office etc. will have their own ideas. For "mechanical" style issues such as this you should look for style guidance from the place your document will get published. A thesis for example should check with the department/school. Check how others have done it. Check for official style guidance from the school. But I did give thumbs up to mh333's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commonly this is done by using a monospaced font - often the same font as used in your code blocks.

Example:
The `greenhouseData` needs to....

See also here:
[What are the conventions for indicating programming variables within text?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/102070/what-are-the-conventions-for-indicating-programming-variables-within-text)
and maybe also
[Proper way to format computer code included in a thesis/dissertation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24498/proper-way-to-format-computer-code-included-in-a-thesis-dissertation)